# Is there a dynamic way to add a prefix to all column names of one table when joining two tables who share some column names?

Tags: sql, database, amazon-redshift

Below are two very small example tables to explain the situation.

**Table a** has columns (**time**, **length**, **height**)

**Table b** has columns (**time**, **length**, **width**)

When I execute a left join I will have **Table c** with columns (**time**, **length**, **height**, **time**, **length**, **width**)

Is there a dynamic way to prefix all of the column names from **Table a** to make the columns unambiguous?

I would like **Table c** to be shown as(**table_a_time**, **table_a_length**, **table_a_height**, **time**, **length**, **width**).

Comment: Redshift does not support any features like this. The interface is a simple SQL. To achieve what you want requires some query generation as @CoffeeNeedCoffee explained. What I would recommend is the [dbt](https://www.getdbt.com/) - it's an open source python project which gives you jinja templating and models dependency for your sql scripts. There you could add a macro to add prefixes to the columns (that's what we did).

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can think of is to dynamically build the SELECT statement into a string that you can later execute.

```sql
DECLARE @fullQuery varchar(max) = ''
SELECT  @fullQuery = 
    'SELECT '  + 
        stuff( /* grab every column from Table A and give it an alias with a prefix */
            (
                select ', table_a.' + column_name + ' as table_a_' + column_name 
                from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns 
                where table_name = 'YOUR_TABLE_NAME_HERE'
                FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'varchar(max)')
        , 1, 2, '') 
    + ', table_b.*
    FROM YOUR_TABLE_NAME_HERE table_a 
    LEFT JOIN YOUR_TABLE_NAME_HERE table_b on table_a.pk = table_b.pk' 

-- SELECT @fullQuery -- debug

EXEC(@fullQuery)
```

This will grab all the columns from Table A, generate the basic SELECT statement that renames every column, then also displays every column from Table B. Works best if you actually want every column from both tables, but you could narrow it down to the individual columns if you knew them beforehand.